# Get Azure AD token on behalf of user - NetCore2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to get the Azure AD token on behalf of user so i can access some resources through Azure AD App ( the app connects to SharePoint Online API).

My problem is getting the token on behalf of user. I added Azure AD app with permisisons as the Auth method in my app (auto added using Visual Studio 2017). Is there any way to get the token on behalf of user using the built-in authentication? (since it already redirects the user to sign in if he isnt already).

I've tried something like this, but i assume this token is for the app, not on behalf of the user (and gives 401 if i try to access SharePoint).

```
string clientId = 'xxxxxxxx';
string clientSecret = 'xxxxxxxxx'
var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://MYSITE.onmicrosoft.com/APPID", credential);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Is there any way to get the token on behalf of user using the built-in authentication? (since it already redirects the user to sign in if he isnt already).

Yes , after user is authenticated, you should acquire an access token for accessing SharePoint Online API/ Microsoft Graph api .

You can use  the OpenID Connect middleware and the Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL.NET) to obtain a JWT bearer token for the signed-in user using the OAuth 2.0 protocol:

```
// Because we signed-in already in the WebApp, the userObjectId is know
string userObjectID = (User.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier"))?.Value;

// Using ADAL.Net, get a bearer token to access the TodoListService
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(AzureAdOptions.Settings.Authority, new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID, HttpContext.Session));
ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(AzureAdOptions.Settings.ClientId, AzureAdOptions.Settings.ClientSecret);
result = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(AzureAdOptions.Settings.TodoListResourceId, credential, new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));
```

You can refer to the code sample : [Calling a web API in an ASP.NET Core web application using Azure AD](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore) . Please replace the resource to SharePoint Online API/ Microsoft Graph api to meet your requirement .

> > I've tried something like this, but i assume this token is for the app, not on behalf of the user (and gives 401 if i try to access SharePoint).

Yes , your codes are using [Client credentials grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) which  use app's own credentials instead of impersonating a user, to authenticate when calling another web service.

Comment: I took a look at the sample, but it is using MVC. What can i use as a replacement for HttpContext.Current since that doesnt seem to exist in AspNetCore ?

Comment: I modified my code with `HttpContextAccessor` for netcore. On load i  did `Session.Get("spotoken")` and on persist i did `.Set("spotoken", CacheId) `. Not sure if thats the right way to do it (havent used sessions in netcore till now), but the code gives me an error saying theres no token in the cache and it needs `AcquireToken()` which as far as i know will redirect the user. Is there something that i did wrong or is that redirect the only way to get the user token?

Comment: @DanteR. Do you follow the client sample(TodoListWebApp) and use OIDC middleware and ADAL to obtain access token ? in that code sample , it use [token cache](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/Utils/NaiveSessionCache.cs) to store the token . when use AcquireTokenSilentAsync , that will check whether current user has token for accessing that resource in cache , if exists , it will direct use that token , if no , it will get the access token for you

Comment: You can also refer to this article which may explain the process better : https://joonasw.net/view/aspnet-core-2-azure-ad-authentication

Comment: My problem is that im rather "newbie" on the whole,auth part and im getting a bit confused so sorry for the lengthy comments. My auth (built with vs 2017) looks like this. `            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
                .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));` The authentication works. Can i use that for the access token or should i switch to manual openid integration? Thanks for taking the time to answer me, i really appreciate it.

Comment: Ive used the sample provided in the article and it works. I'll have to break it down to see how its built, but i might as well use that as a starting point. Many thanks!

Comment: @NanYu: can you shed some light here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/56546947/114029

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to get the Azure AD token on behalf of user so i can access some resources through Azure AD App ( the app connects to SharePoint Online API).

If we want to access the sharepoint, we need to create an app in Azure AD that has permissions to access the API. And don't forget to grant premissions.

> The **Microsoft Graph** enables developers to access data from multiple Microsoft Cloud services including:
>
> - Azure AD (for users and groups)
> - Office 365
> - **SharePoint Online**
> - Exchange Online
> - OneDrive for Business
> - OneNote
> - Planner
> - Excel
> - OneDrive Consumer
> - Outlook.com

[image]

Another thing is that the resource should be  `https://graph.microsoft.com` not your application.

The following is the demo code

```
 private static async Task<string> GetAppTokenAsync(string tenantId, string clientId, string username,string password)
 {  
    var graphResource = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
     string aadInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantId + "/oauth2/token";
     //Instantiate an AuthenticationContext for my directory (see authString above).
     AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(aadInstance, false);
     // Create a ClientCredential that will be used for authentication.
     //This is where the Client ID and Key / Secret from the Azure Management Portal is used.
     UserPasswordCredential credential = new UserPasswordCredential(username, password); //username is email format
     // Acquire an access token from Azure AD to access the Azure Microsoft Graph(the resource)
     //  using the Client ID and Key / Secret as credentials.
     AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResource, clientId, credential);
     // Return the access token.
     return authenticationResult.AccessToken;

 }
```

Comment: The app is already created in Azure AD. Your answer isn't really what i'm looking for. I'm already logging the user in using the built-in Azure AD auth and i do not like the idea of having the user type their username and password (since they already get redirected to log in when accessing the app).

Comment: As Nan Yu mentioned  that you can use the OpenID Connect middleware and the Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL.NET) to obtain a JWT bearer token for the signed-in user using the OAuth 2.0 protocol during the user login. Then you could use the token to access the graph resource.

Comment: Theres a different middleware in my implementation, see the comments on the below answer. I will try using that to get the token (not sure if it works). Thanks for trying to help me out, appreciate it !